# How to convert object into string in javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a function that should take as an argument of the object and return a string

The code I wrote.

```
function check(obj) {
  return obj.toString();
}
```

Comment: `JSON.stringify(object)` --> BOOM ! -> you got a string

Comment: Not working this way. I tried.

Comment: Yeah because JSON is encoded with double quotes around each property name and value if it's a string.  So you would have to check `actual.includes('"name": "Ant", "age": 28,.. etc)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```js
let toString = ({name, age, language}) => `name: ${name}, age: ${age}, language: ${language}`;

const david = { name: 'David', age: 22, language: 'PHP' };

console.log(toString(david));
```

If you'd like to be more generic:

```js
let toString = obj => Object.entries(obj).map(([k, v]) => `${k}: ${v}`).join(', ');

const david = { name: 'David', age: 22, language: 'PHP', favoriteFood: 'blue' };

console.log(toString(david));
```

Comment: Thanks. All 3 test passed but I got error "returns a whole string with all of the user's details". can u please help me?

Comment: You'll need to provide more details. You should also look into how to debug code.

Answer (score 9):

If your object is like

```
const obj = { name: "John", age: 30, city: "New York" };
```

Use the JavaScript function `JSON.stringify()` to convert it into a string.
Like this `JSON.stringify(obj)`.
then you will get this string:

`"{"name":"John","age":30,"city":"New York"}"`

Answer (score 2):

```
var data = {name: "john", age: 30}
var str = JSON.stringify(data)  // "{\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":30}"
var btoas = btoa(str)  // "eyJuYW1lIjoiam9obiIsImFnZSI6MzB9"
var atobs = atob(btoas)  // "{\"name\":\"john\",\"age\":30}"
var myRealData = JSON.parse(atobs)  //{name: "john", age: 30}

` BOYAA !! `
```

Comment: You've not defined `btoa` nor `atob`. Therefore this is not a working solution and should be deleted.

Comment: it's just for testing string values. sometimes object code is changed to `btoa` can work when changed to `atob` the value is `[Object object]`

Comment: `atob` and `btoa` are available in the browser as are the `alert` codes.

Comment: object to string is needed, for example to store browser cookies. code works when using `btoa(JSON.stringify(code))`

Answer (score 1):

Apply this technique if you want to convert an object to a string without applying the JSON.stringify() function

```js
let obj = { 
  x: 1, 
  y: 'HelloWorld',
  toString: function(){
    return `${this.x}, ${this.y}`;
  }
};

let result = String(obj);

console.log(result, 'type --> ', typeof result);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function check(obj) {
  console.log(typeof obj) // object
  let res = JSON.stringify(obj)
  console.log(typeof res) // string
  return res;
}
let example = {name: "John"}
console.log(check(example)) // {"name":"John"}
```

Answer (score 0):

1% of the time, you might need something besides json. Almost always you need json, but...

Sometimes you need a JavaScript string, not json. Like when you're filling in a graphql template.

It's just like the json string, but it doesn't have quotes around the attributes.

```js
export const toJavascriptString =
  (obj: any) => JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\"([\w_-]+?)\"\:/g, '$1:')


var obj = {a: 'wsd', b: 2}
var str = JSON.stringify(obj).replace(/\"([\w_-]+?)\"\:/g, '$1:')
console.log(str)
```

> {a:"wsd",b:2}